# How to target inactive elements on html page?

Tags: html, css

I need some help in being able to target some dots on my slider that are not active. What I am try to do is state that if a dot is active (.slick-active will be adsigned to the element), the color of the dot is yellow (#FFFF00), else if the dot is not active, the color of the dot should be white (keeping its opactiy).

Currently if a dot is not active, it's yellow with opacity and I am not sure how to target it.

Below is the screenshot of the dots:

[image]

Below is sample html and css (html shows three dot and not 5 to reduce code):

```css
.wp-block-eedee-block-gutenslider {
  --gutenslider-arrow-color: #FFFF00 !important;
  --gutenslider-arrow-hover-color: #d8d800 !important;
  --gutenslider-dot-color: #FFFF00 !important;
  --gutenslider-dot-hover-color: #FFFF00 !important;
  --gutenslider-arrow-bg-color: #000000 !important;
  --gutenslider-arrow-bg-hover-color: #474747 !important;
}

.slick-dots>li:not(.slick-active) {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-block-eedee-block-gutenslider">
  <ul class="slick-dots" role="tablist" style="display: block;">
    <li class="slick-active" role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control00" aria-controls="slick-slide00" aria-label="1 of 5" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">1</button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control01" aria-controls="slick-slide01" aria-label="2 of 5" tabindex="-1">2</button></li>
    <li role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control02" aria-controls="slick-slide02" aria-label="3 of 5" tabindex="-1">3</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]  - you CSS does not have any slick

Comment: Sorry I thought I pasted it, I have added it now.

Comment: I made you a snippet. It does not look anything like your image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approach it should work out. The element li will have .slick-active when slick dot will be active if it does not have slick-active class it means it is inactive.

```
/* Styles for inactive dot */  
.slick-dots > li{
   color : white ;  
}

/* Styles for active dot */  
.slick-dots > li.slick-active{
   color : yellow ;  
}
```